# Grab Instagram photo from an user account but different hashtag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, instagram, hashtag

I want to pull Instagram photo from one single user but different hashtag from he/she.

Currently I can only pull either from a userId or pull photo from many people with the same hashtag.

**How can I pull certain hashtag from only one user?**

this is my code to pull photo from certain hashtag:

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">


 new Instafeed({ 
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'domo',
        clientId: 'xxx',
        image_size: 'standard_resolution',
    }).run(); // Call run after initialization



</script>
```

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Instagram API does not support what you are trying to do, pull media for a single user for a single hashtag. You would need to pull media for a user using the `/users/user-id/media/recent` endpoint and then loop through the results looking for the hashtag yourself.

Comment: Is that Instagram API allow to grab photo caption?

Comment: Yes, look for the Caption property in the response for each media.